# Array combine into associative array

Tags: php, associative-array

I need to add the values of an associative array to another one.

```
$a = array(4=>2,5=>5);
$b = arrray(array(0=>0,1=>4,2=>10,3=>1000),array()...);
```

What I'm expecting to get is a third array ($c) like the one below where the content of $b follows the content of $a:

```
$c = array(array(4=>2,5=>5,0=>0,1=>4,2=>10,3=>1000),array(4=>2,5=>5....));
```

This is what I've written (not working):

```
$c = array();
foreach ($possible_opp_action as $sub) {
    $c[] = array_push($to_merge,array_values($sub));

}
```

Comment: An associative array has string keys, your example arrays all have numeric keys... can you clarify exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = array(4=>2,5=>5);
$b = array(array(0=>0,1=>4,2=>10,3=>1000),
           array(0=>0,1=>40,2=>100,3=>2000),
           array(4=>10)
          );

$c = array();
foreach($b as $tmp) {
    $c[] = $a+$tmp;
}

var_dump($c);
```

Unlike array_merge, this will maintain numeric keys... but watch out for duplicate keys

Answer (score 0):

You need array_merge.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Note the handling of duplicate keys:

*Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.
If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.
Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.*

**EDIT:**

I may have not read the question right - please clarify...

Do you want all the array items in a single array, or an array with the original arrays as items in it (an array of arrays)?

IE: 
c = array(a=a, b=b, c=c, etc.) <- can be done with array_merge($a, $b, $c, etc)

vs

c = array( 
    b = array(a=a, b=b, c=c, etc), 
    a=array(d=d, e=e, etc.) 
) <- should be done by just concatenating the next array on the end like this (and skip the $c altogether):

```
$c[] = $b;
$c[] = $a;

//or

$c = array();
foreach ($possible_opp_action as $sub) {
    $c[] = $sub;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$c = array();
foreach ($b as $bb) {
    $c[] = array_merge($a,$bb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$c = array_merge($b, $a)
```

help in http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need `$b` in original form:

```
<?php

$a = array(4=>2,5=>5);
$b = array(array(0=>0,1=>4,2=>10,3=>1000),array());

foreach ($b as &$ref) {
    $ref = $a + $ref;
}

var_dump($b);
```

Otherwise:

```
<?php

$a = array(4=>2,5=>5);
$b = array(array(0=>0,1=>4,2=>10,3=>1000),array());

$c = array();

foreach ($b as &$ref) {
    $c[] = $a + $ref;
}

var_dump($c);
```